# Attaching Visual Studio debugger to Windows service -- "attach" greyed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I am trying to attach to a windows service using Visual Studio 2010 → *Debug* → *Attach to process* command. When I scroll through the list of processes my Windows service is greyed out and the attach button is also greyed out.

I have tried changing the service account to local service, my account, etc., but it remains greyed out. Is there a way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Could it be because the service is in release mode?

Comment: Good thought but i had already checked that is was in debug mode.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I usually have the same issue and I take care of it by adding a boolean to my configuration that triggers a debug launch. You can launch a Visual Studio debugger instance that attaches to your Windows service process by calling this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

What's nice is that you can call it wherever you wish in your code.

Comment: I like this. A nice simple way to launch a debugger from a service. Next question is there a way to remotely attach using this method if the service is installed on another machine?

Comment: Don't have an immediate answer but that would be beneficial to me as well. I'll see if there's an easy way to achieve it and if so I'll edit my answer to include that solution as well.

Answer (score 39):

In Visual Studio 2010, on the 'Attach to Process' dialog, check the two check boxes at the bottom that say '**Show processes from all users**' and '**Show processes in all sessions**'.

On doing that I found that I had my process show up twice, one running as *System* and one running under my local Windows login. I am not sure why (any input on this would be great!), but I was able to attach to the not-grayed-out one that showed up and was also able to step through my code this way.

The second one was the servicename.vshost.exe process as Ozz pointed out in the comments.

If you still do not see it, make sure your service is still running. Sometimes you might have a failing service that started and automatically stopped and therefore doesn't show up in the attach to options.

Comment: this worked for me. What I noticed is that the "greyed" out one, is actually the myservice.vshost.exe process, but I didn't notice as the name was quite long and the end was hidden by the column. The one that shows up using PreethA instructions is the real process to attach to. I'm guessing the 1 of the 2 PreethA saw was his myservice.vshost.exe

Comment: In my case I had to check the box that said 'Show all processes in all sessions'.  For some reason after doing that it was no longer grayed out.

Answer (score 8):

Not only did I have to select `show processes from all users` and the `show processes in all sessions` check boxes; I also had to click the `Select` button and then choose the `Managed` code.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you run Visual Studio as an administrator. It will require administrator rights to attach to a running service.

Comment: Tried this but no luck. I can attach to other services listed in the process list, just not the one i need to. :)

Answer (score 2):

After installing the Windows service, start it. Then in Visual Studio open the *Attach to process* window (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), find your process and select it and click *Attach Button* in the bottom of the window.

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted, it is exactly what Microsoft suggests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications

Comment: true! .. Additionally, I put in a Thread.Sleep(25000) to delay the execution and give me enough time to attach to the process. Of course I built in debug mode and copy pasted the exe and pdb files into the deployment folder.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have permissions to attach to the service.  Do you have admin privileges on the desktop?  Many corporations do not allow this by default, supposedly to assist in securing their environment.

Comment: Yea, i have admin privs and i tried to right click and run as administrator in vs to see if that helped. No luck.

Comment: Are you in a position to try the Alternate Debugging Strategies described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(VS.80).aspx ?

Comment: Steve, thanks for the link. I had actually looked at that page but did not see the alternate strategies at the bottom. I have used a console to test services before and that is a pretty decentalternative.

Comment: Welcome.  I'd be interested to know how this was or is resolved for you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing the way the setup was generated, from RELEASE to DEBUG. And then, I installed the service and attached as usual.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue today with none of the previous solutions working. As it turns out, it is not possible to attach to a process if you have a [ProcDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) session monitoring that process.

Answer (score -2):

Use menu *Tools* → *Attach to Process*. Simply check *Show Processes* from all users at the bottom left. Sort by *Process* and try looking for your Windows service.